# Crunch modify wordlist at specific rules

Tags: dictionary

I have a dictionary list which I would like to modify and create a new list with the following rules: `crunch 9 9 -t ,@@@@@@%%`

Is this possible? (Removing all the words that do not match the specified rules.)

Comment: I'm confused. Why modify the existing list and why not just create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter your wordlist using grep:

```
grep -E '[A-Z][a-z]{6}[0-9]{2}' wordlist.txt > newlist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost work, it greps the words with 7 chars but with 4 digits instead of 2 at the end. If I change it to {1}, same result. How could I fix this?

Comment: Ah there was a $ needed. 
grep -E '[A-Z][a-z]{6}[0-9]{2}$' wordlist.txt > newlist.txt